# Slide Up on hover, slide down off hover (without unique class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to make a div slide up on hover of its container and slide down when you mouse off,  slide up works fine but I cannot make this slide out, it just disappears straight away.

There is no way for me to uniquely identify each container as the information is brought out of a loop I have no control over.

I understand why this is happening - it is because the class no longer has a display block off hover and so disappears, but I don't know how to fix. I have tried delays with no luck too.

**Fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/u7ttx2dd/2/

HTML:

```
             <main>
                <section class="entries">
            <section class="entry">
            <div class="container">
                <img width="800" height="533" src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg">
                <div class="title">
                     Title
                </div>
                <div class="hover" style="bottom: -1000px;">
                    <div class="title">
                         Title
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus nec quam et dui bibendum convallis. Morbi nec porta elit. Pellentesque
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </section>
            <section class="entry">
            <div class="container">
                <img width="800" height="533" src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg">
                <div class="title">
                     Title
                </div>
                <div class="hover" style="bottom: -1000px;">
                    <div class="title">
                         Title
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus nec quam et dui bibendum convallis. Morbi nec porta elit. Pellentesque
                    </p>
                </div>
            </section>
             </main>
```

**jQuery**

```
           jQuery(".entries .entry .container").hover(
                function() {
                    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
                    jQuery(".entries .entry .container.selected .hover").stop().animate({bottom: '0'}, 1000);
                },
                function() {
                    jQuery(".entries .entry .container .hover").stop().animate({bottom: '-1000'}, 1000);
                    jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
                }
            );
```

**HTML**

```
            main .entry {
                overflow: hidden;
                display: inline;
                float: left;
                width: 33.33333125%;
                padding: 0 8px;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            main .entry img {
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: 180px;
            }
            main .entry a {
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none
            }
            main .entry .container {
                position: relative
            }
            main .entry .container.selected .hover {
                display: block
            }
            main .entry .title {
                background: #000;
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 18px;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            main .entry .hover {
                background: #23252b;
                color: #fff;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                bottom: -1000px;
                display: none;
                padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            }
            main .entry .hover .title {
                padding: 0;
                background: none;
                width: 80%;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            main .entry .hover .moresmall:hover {
                background-color: #2f3035
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the 'display' styles from the CSS, leaving that up to jQuery, and it seems to have fixed the issues you have.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7ttx2dd/6/

```
main .entry {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333125%;
    padding: 0 8px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
main .entry img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
}
main .entry a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none
}
main .entry .container {
    position: relative
}
main .entry .container.selected .hover {

}
main .entry .title {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #000;
}
main .entry .hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -1000px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
main .entry .hover .title {
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
main .entry .hover .moresmall:hover {
    background-color: #2f3035
}
```

Comment: daaammnnn its amazing how you can miss simple things when doing everything else! doh! thanks for stating the obvious! :)